# Trying to push an array from an .each() into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to push an associative array into an empty object and it's giving me the error:

`Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined`

The code I'm trying is

```
var arr = {};
$(".proj").each(function() {
 arr.push[{name: "name"}];
});
console.log(arr);
```

I think it's something to do with the scope of `arr` but i'm unsure, any help is appreciated

Comment: Is `.proj` really an object?

Comment: An Object has no `push` method... [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Yes @staypuftman https://gyazo.com/9706c40194dfc4fdaf8ce818b91873f5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = [];
$(".proj").each(function() {
 arr.push({name: "name"})
});
console.log(arr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="proj">
  hello
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I can't believe I did something so stupid. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a timer before I can accept an answer @Geeky

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object `arr={}` is an object not an array & it does not have `push` property.

Better do like this

```
var arr = [];
$(".proj").each(function() {
 arr.push({name: "name"});
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Bonus credit: When i do this how come when I AJAX it across and return `var_dump($_POST);` name doesn't have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Tyr below code

```
var arr = [];
$(".proj").each(function() {
arr.push({name: "name"});
});
console.log(arr);
```

when you declare

```
  var arr = []
```

then its an array

and if you declare like

```
 var arr = {}
```

then its object.

also push is as function

so you can use below syntax to add element to array

```
 arr.push("element");
```

and to add element to object use

```
arr["index"] = "value"
```